# Exploring a UML Sequence diagram via ACCELEO in the Eclipse Modeling Framework

Tags: uml, eclipse-emf, modeling, acceleo

I am exploring a UML (or SysML) model, defined via TopCased, through an ACCELEO script. The problem is that for sequence diagrams (Interaction) I can not get how to reproduce the modelled trace (a sequence of occurrence specification representing operation calls). In the model an Interaction is represented as a container of Message Occurrence Specification, Behavior Execution Specification, Message and Lifeline. I need to know where and how the sequence of execution in time is expressed by means of these constructs.

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Could you fill the blanks in your question? It is currently quite hard to understand :).

Comment: I am sorry I didn't realize it blanked tagged words :)

Comment: And... sorry, I don't know the UML (and SYSML) models enough to help here :s. You may want to ask the question on the Eclipse UML forum (http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/117/)?